# PL/SQL: How to write XML file?

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

How do I write to XML file?
I use the following code but I keep getting errors. Please heeeellllppppp!!
Here is the common error:
`wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PUT_LINE'`
If I change something, other errors appear.

```
set serveroutput on
DECLARE
    v_filePointer           utl_file.file_type;
    v_filePointer := UTL_FILE.fopen('Myname_DIR', 'Myname' || to_char(sysdate+1,'DD-MON-YYYY') || '.xml', 'w');
    Ctx               DBMS_XMLGEN.ctxHandle;
    xml               CLOB := NULL;
    temp_xml          CLOB := NULL;
    v_query_date      DATE := TRUNC(sysdate+1) ;
    QUERY    VARCHAR2(2000) := 'SELECT tni, sum(volume) tni_total 
                          FROM v_nem_rm16
                          WHERE DAY = '''||v_query_date||''' GROUP BY tni';

BEGIN
    common.log(query);
--    utl_file.put_line(query);
    Ctx := DBMS_XMLGEN.newContext(QUERY);
    DBMS_XMLGen.setRowsetTag( Ctx, 'ROWSETTAG' );
    DBMS_XMLGen.setRowTag( Ctx, 'ROWTAG' );
    temp_xml := DBMS_XMLGEN.getXML(Ctx);

IF temp_xml IS NOT NULL THEN
    IF xml IS NOT NULL THEN
        DBMS_LOB.APPEND( xml, temp_xml );
    ELSE
        xml := temp_xml;
        utl_file.put_line(v_filePointer,'xml.file');
        utl_file.fclose(v_filePointer);
    END IF;
END IF;

    DBMS_XMLGEN.closeContext( Ctx );
    utl_file.put_line(substr(xml, 1, 1950));
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only make declarations in the `declare` section, so this line is not valid where it is:

```
v_filePointer := UTL_FILE.fopen('Myname_DIR', ...
```

You can either move it after the `begin` keyword, or combine it with the declaration:

```
    v_filepointer utl_file.file_type :=
        utl_file.fopen('Myname_DIR', 'Myname' || to_char(sysdate + 1, 'DD-MON-YYYY') || '.xml', 'w');
```

The first argument to `utl_file.put_line` should be the file ID, `v_filePointer`:

```
utl_file.put_line(v_filepointer, substr(xml, 1, 1950));
```

It's not a good idea to concatenate a date value directly into a dynamic query, because you are trusting to the default date format (although it can be argued that whatever the format and language, it will be the same for reading as it is for writing, so even if you don't know what that format is, it will work. However, I would still call it poor practice.) I would prefer to use an explicit format to construct a standard date literal.

Putting that together, I get this:

```
declare
    v_filepointer utl_file.file_type := utl_file.fopen('Myname_DIR', 'Myname' || to_char(sysdate + 1, 'DD-MON-YYYY') || '.xml', 'w');
    ctx           dbms_xmlgen.ctxhandle;
    xml           clob := null;
    temp_xml      clob := null;
    v_query_date  date := trunc(sysdate + 1);
    query         varchar2(2000) := 'select tni, sum(volume) tni_total 
                      from v_nem_rm16
                      where day = date ''' || to_char(v_query_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') || ''' group by tni';
begin
    common.log(query);

    utl_file.put_line(v_filepointer, query);

    ctx := dbms_xmlgen.newcontext(query);
    dbms_xmlgen.setrowsettag(ctx, 'ROWSETTAG');
    dbms_xmlgen.setrowtag(ctx, 'ROWTAG');
    temp_xml := dbms_xmlgen.getxml(ctx);

    if temp_xml is not null then
        if xml is not null then
            dbms_lob.append(xml, temp_xml);
        else
            xml := temp_xml;
            utl_file.put_line(v_filepointer, 'xml.file');
            utl_file.fclose(v_filepointer);
        end if;
    end if;

    dbms_xmlgen.closecontext(ctx);
    utl_file.put_line(v_filepointer, substr(xml, 1, 1950));
    utl_file.fclose_all;
end;
```